# How to find RSS feed of a particular website?

Tags: rss

How to find RSS feed of a particular website? Whether there is any particular way to find it?

Comment: Also, it is important to note that certain websites may not have feeds at all. In that case, you will not be able to find any RSS source code such as mentioned above. What I mean by this is - "Not all websites/blogs have RSS feeds".

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You might be able to find it by looking at the source of the home page (or blog). Look for a line that looks like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS Feed" href="http://example.org/rss" />
```

The href value will be where the RSS is located.

Comment: This is a standard one right so on every website I can look for this right?

Comment: It is although the title attribute's value might change.

Comment: Is there a similar way to find atom feeds?

Comment: @Cort3z You bet! There may be something like this in there somewhere: `<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="ATOM Feed" href="http://example.org/atom" />`. The key is to look for `application/atom+xml`.

Comment: @FrancoisDeschenes Nice. It does seem to be a bit fragile though. Not everyone actually add the type in there. Maybe the best bet is actually to search for links with the keyword feed, rss or atom in it.

Comment: @Cort3z - There really is no perfect solution here. You could consider looking for an XML sitemap or crawl known paths but otherwise it's up to the author of the feed to choose how it'll ultimately be publicized.

Comment: Or if you want it as a CSS selector, just fire up the console (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J` in Chrome) and enter `$('link[type="application/rss+xml"]')[0]['href']`.

Answer (score 16):

There are multiple ways to get the RSS feed of the website.

What you can do is get the page source of a website and search for this link tag of `type="application/rss+xml"`

That will contain the RSS feed of that website, if any.

Here is a simple program in python that will print the RSS feed of any website, if any.

```python
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

def get_rss_feed(website_url):
    if website_url is None:
        print("URL should not be null")
    else:
        source_code = requests.get(website_url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.find_all("link", {"type" : "application/rss+xml"}):
            href = link.get('href')
            print("RSS feed for " + website_url + "is -->" + str(href))

get_rss_feed("http://www.extremetech.com/")
```

Save this file with the .py extension and run it. It will give you the rss feed url of that website.

Google also provides APIs to find the RSS feeds of a website.
Please find them here: [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/reference)

Comment: The Google's API is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all urls on your website and then find one that's containing "rss".

Method above maybe won't work in some cases if url in *href* tag looks something like **feed.xml**, so in that case you'll need to loop through all tags containing *href* **AND** *rss*, then just parse url from *href* attribute.

If you want to do this through browser, press CTRL+U to view source, then CTRL+F to open find window and then just type in **rss**. *RSS Feed url should appear immediately.*

Answer (score 0):

Firefox's Tools menu now has a "Page Info" command.  One of the tabs in that tool displays discovered feed info.

Comment: Not anymore as of Firefox 64

Comment: Plugins to the rescue:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/feedbroreader/

Answer (score -3):

I needed to find sites with RSS feeds.  Using Visual Studio (VB) I was able do that. Following code is just a fragment.  It dies after the loop finishes but it does find any ref to an rss page on the site.  That's all I needed so I never quite finished it.  But it worked for me.

Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

...
        Dim request As WebRequest
        request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.[site]")

```
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)

    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
    Dim intPos As Integer

    Do
        line = reader.ReadLine()
        intPos = line.IndexOf("/rss")
        If intPos > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show(line + " " + intPos.ToString)
        End If
    Loop While Not line Is Nothing
```

....