# How to find RSS feed for a web site?

Tags: xml, rss, feed

I know we can look up 'type="application/rss+xml"' in the html content of a web site to find a RSS feed for it:
[How to find RSS feed of a particular website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327146/how-to-find-rss-feed-of-a-particular-website)

But some web sites doesn't contain 'type="application/rss+xml"', but it still has a RSS feed.
For example, the RSS feed for http://blog.linkedin.com/ is http://feeds.feedburner.com/LinkedInBlog.

Is there any way I can look up a RSS feed for a web site? Is there an API or commercial/free website service? I know Google feed api, https://developers.google.com/feed/, but it has been deprecated.

Thanks.

Comment: Typically you'd use [RSS Autodiscovery](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-autodiscovery), but not all blogs add the appropriate `link`s. Annoyingly, the LinkedIn blog seems to be WordPress-based, but while WordPress supports this out of the box, LinkedIn's theme has specifically removed the autodiscovery links. (That Google API didn't do any discovery even when it wasn't deprecated, from what I remember. You still had to give it a feed URL to process.)