# python Beautiful Soup - cannot find the feed URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, rss, feed

I am using the [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4)  module of python to get the feed URL of any website.  But the code does not work for all sites. For example it works for http://www.extremetech.com/ but not for http://cnn.com/. Actually http://cnn.com/ redirects to https://edition.cnn.com/. So I used the later one but of no luck. But I found by googling  that the feed of CNN is [here](http://edition.cnn.com/services/rss/) .

My code follows:

```
import urllib.parse
import requests
import feedparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def findfeed(site):
    user_agent = {
        'User-agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17'}
    raw = requests.get(site, headers = user_agent).text
    result = []
    possible_feeds = []
    #html = bs4(raw,"html5lib")
    html = bs4(raw,"html.parser")
    feed_urls = html.findAll("link", rel="alternate")



    for f in feed_urls:
        t = f.get("type",None)
        if t:
            if "rss" in t or "xml" in t:
                href = f.get("href",None)
                if href:
                    possible_feeds.append(href)
    parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(site)
    base = parsed_url.scheme+"://"+parsed_url.hostname
    atags = html.findAll("a")
    for a in atags:
        href = a.get("href",None)
        if href:
            if "xml" in href or "rss" in href or "feed" in href:
                possible_feeds.append(base+href)
    for url in list(set(possible_feeds)):
        f = feedparser.parse(url)
        if len(f.entries) > 0:
            if url not in result:
                result.append(url)

    for result_indiv in result:
                print( result_indiv,end='\n  ')
    #return(result)




# findfeed("http://www.extremetech.com/")
# findfeed("http://www.cnn.com/")
findfeed("https://edition.cnn.com/")
```

How can I make the code work for all sites for example https://edition.cnn.com/ ? I am using python 3.

**EDIT 1:** If I need to use any module other than Beautiful Soup, I am ready to do that

Comment: `requests` follows redirects; requesting `www.cnn.com` redirects you to `edition.cnn.com`; the response you get is for the last part of the redirects. Do a get for `www` and look at the response `.history` and `.url` attributes, and you'll see you end up on `edition`.

Comment: RSS and atom feeds *can* be autodiscoverable via `link` tags, but this is by no means a given. The CNN homepage has no such links, so you are out of luck there.

Comment: A quick google leads to http://edition.cnn.com/services/rss/, but I don't know where CNN is linking to that page. Plugging `edition.cnn.com` into an establish RSS reader with discovery support (inoreader.com) shows that it too can't find feeds.

Comment: Istiaque, you should read some documentation on how to make a web API. If you do so, you will realize that while some sites may follow a common convention, nothing requires them to do so, so you cannot assume that a site even has rss feeds, much less links to them from their homepage.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make the code work for all sites

You can't. Not every site follows the best practices.

It is [*recommended* that the site homepage includes a `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" ...>` or `<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" ...>` element](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-autodiscovery), but CNN doesn't follow the recommendation. There is no way around this.

> But I found by googling that the feed of CNN is here.

That is not the homepage, and CNN has not provided any means to discover it. There is currently no *automated method* to discover what sites have made this error.

> Actually http://cnn.com/ redirects to https://edition.cnn.com/

Requests handles redirection for you automatically:

```
>>> response = requests.get('http://cnn.com')
>>> response.url
'https://edition.cnn.com/'
>>> response.history
[<Response [301]>, <Response [301]>, <Response [302]>]
```

> If I need to use any module other than BeautifulSoup, I am ready to do that

This is not a problem a module can solve. Some sites don't implement autodiscovery or do not implement it correctly.

For example, established RSS feed software that implement autodiscovery support (like the online https://inoreader.com), can't find the CNN feeds *either*, unless you use the specific `/services/rss` URL you found with Googling.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327146/how-to-find-rss-feed-of-a-particular-website). This should work perfectly:

```
feeds = html.findAll(type='application/rss+xml') + html.findAll(type='application/atom+xml')
```

Trying that on the [CNN RSS service](http://edition.cnn.com/services/rss/) works perfectly. Your main problem is that the edition.cnn.com does not have any traces of RSS in any way or fashion.

Comment: What more types other than rss and atom do I need to look for ?

Comment: That I don't know. Just that these two are most widely used to my knowledge :)

Comment: my python shell kept waiting and waiting with http://edition.cnn.com/services/rss/ as input.  Won't https://edition.cnn.com/ or http://cnn.com/ work ?

Comment: If edition.cnn.com/services/rss has a RSS link, then https://edition.cnn.com/ also has one, right ?

Comment: No, it would have been user friendlier if it did. But just because they are on the same domain does not in anyway mean that it will contain RSS feeds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165288/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-the-pjot).

Comment: You could use a CSS selector to get one list in one step: `soup.select('link[type$=+xml]')` (bit of a shortcut) or `soup.select('link[type=application/rss+xml],link[type=application/atom+xml]')` (more explicit).